# Sorting an "output" of a program

Tags: c, unix, sorting, output

Say I run a program which makes several printf statements over the course of its running. Naturally every time it hits a printf command it will print. How would I go about instead of printing it, "store" it, and then at the end of the program, take all the lines that should have been printed, sort it AND THEN print it.

e.g.

```
Run Program
prints "File1 90"
prints "File2 30"
prints "File3 40"
End Program
```

---

```
Run Program
prints "File1 90" (don't actually print it out)
prints "File2 30" (don't actually print it out)
prints "File3 40" (don't actually print it out)
Take print statements and rearrange them by numerical order, then print
Program prints:
prints "File2 30"
prints "File3 40"
prints "File1 90"
```

I think I have to use a unix shell command within my C program such as 
   `sort -k2n,2 -k1,1 myprogram`

Comment: Do you want the *program* to sort its own output?  Is there any reason you couldn't just pipe the output through `sort`?

Comment: Yup, this ^. You have all the tools you need for the job on unix. Just use it.

Comment: How would I do that within the program?
I realize that I could pipe the output through sort, but how would I do that within the program so its not a command I have to type in afterwards

Comment: you wrap your program in a script, that has a command line like `myProgram arg1 file [file ...n] | sort`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to redirect the `stdout` to file

```
freopen( "file.txt", "w", stdout );
```

and then feed the file to `sort` with `-k 2` arguments, since you want to sort on second column (?)

And as for the command/s refer to this [example](http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/category/pipes/).

It ilustrates the basics.

Comment: Yes I think @iccthedral said is the better way , Normally what I am doing is **./program 2>&1 | tee prgm.log** , So you can view the o/p of the program while running and the same time it will redirect all o/p to the log file too, later you can **grep** the log file using as per your requirement!